# how to make the list in python with 2 lists vertical to each other

Tags: python

this is what I have so far

```
print("KPH\tMPH")
kph = list([60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130])
for item in kph:
    conversion = .6214
    mph = [item * conversion for item in kph]
    continue
print(kph, mph)
```

I am trying to make the output look like this:

[output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D87K9.png)

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
KPH_TO_MPH = 0.6213711922


def main() -> None:
    kph = [60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130]
    mph = [v * KPH_TO_MPH for v in kph]
    print(f'KPH\tMPH')
    for k, m in zip(kph, mph):
        print(f'{k}\t{m:.3f}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
KPH MPH
60  37.282
70  43.496
80  49.710
90  55.923
100 62.137
110 68.351
120 74.565
130 80.778
```

Comment: @CryptoFool I saw OP's image. Having a fixed-width column doesn't match what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip, it will group elements from the first list with the second, and so on.
`kph = [60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130]
mph = [37.284, 43.498, 49.712, 55.926, 62.14, 68.354, 74.568, 80.782]`

for k,m in zip(kph,mph):
print("KPH: {}\tMPH: {}".format(k,m))

Output:
`KPH: 60      MPH: 37.284
KPH: 70      MPH: 43.498
KPH: 80      MPH: 49.712
KPH: 90      MPH: 55.926
KPH: 100     MPH: 62.14
KPH: 110     MPH: 68.354
KPH: 120     MPH: 74.568
KPH: 130     MPH: 80.782`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that doesn't rely on the tab character being good enough to keep your columns aligned.  In the general case, and for wider values, it won't be.

```
kph = [60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130]
mph = [item * .6214 for item in kph]

print(f"{'MPH':5} KPH")
for m, k in zip(mph, kph):
    print(f"{k:<5} {m:3.6}")
```

Result:

```
MPH   KPH
60    37.284
70    43.498
80    49.712
90    55.926
100   62.14
110   68.354
120   74.568
130   80.782
```

If your data was less predictable, you could compute the first padding value based on the max width of your first column of data and add it dynamically to the format specifier.  I'll leave that to you though.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i would approach to solve the problem. I would convert the list to a pandas dataframe, create a new column by multiplying the initial column with the conversion rate .

```
import pandas as pd

kph = list([60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130])
#print(kph)    
df = pd.DataFrame({'KPH':kph}) #convert list to dataframe KPH column
df['MPH'] = df['KPH']* 0.6214  #create a new column for conversion MPH column
#print(df)
```